# GUI for Mono port of .NET 4 application using WPF

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, mono, porting

I've decided to port a little C# .NET application over to linux.
It uses .NET 4, and the author (not me) decided to use WPF because he had performance issues with Winforms.

http://www.mono-project.com/Gui_Toolkits shows quite a lot of possible options for me to use, but I'm relatively new to C# and even more so to Mono. I need it to be fast, and preferably fairly lightweight.

What would you recommend and why?

I want to know which GUI kit to go with for performance and easy of porting, given that I'm new to Mono and the original .NET app uses WPF.

Comment: This question would fit better on programmers.stackexchange.com or in chat.  It isn't really a question with a single answer.

Comment: Well, you might be right, in which case someone will migrate it. However, I don't really see this as something for `professional programmers interested in conceptual questions about software development`. I just want to know which gui kit to go with given that I'm new to Mono and the original .NET app uses WPF.

Comment: @IskarJarak Can you share your experiences ? How did it go what should others keep in mind for starting a similar project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go with [Gtk#](http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharp). It has a nice performance and monodevelop comes with a [design tool](http://monodevelop.com/Stetic_GUI_Designer) to help you draw your interface.